# Returning error value in reflect.MakeFunc

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to create an return a function in golang which has a return type of (SomeStruct, error) (standard error interface)

```
fn := func (args []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
    database := mongoConnectorInstance.GetDatabase()
    defer database.Session.Close()

    selector := bson.M{
        field : args[0].Interface(),
    }

    newValue := reflect.New(fieldFunctionValue.Type().Out(0))
    newValueInterface := newValue.Interface()
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(newValueInterface))

    err := database.C(collection).Find(selector).One(newValueInterface)

    secondValue := reflect.ValueOf(err)
    return []reflect.Value {
        newValue.Elem(),
        secondValue,
    }
}

resultFunctionValue := reflect.MakeFunc(fieldFunctionValue.Type(), fn)
```

If err returned by `.One` function is null, I get address pointer error on this line, internally in golang :

```
panic("reflect: function created by MakeFunc using " + funcName(f) +
                    " returned wrong type: have " +
                    out[i].typ.String() + " for " + typ.String())
```

I have tried to change the line of secondValue assignment to :

```
secondValue := reflect.ValueOf((error)(nil))
```

in the case where `err == nil`, however the problem did not go away.

If I create a dummy error struct that implements the interface error and return that, ignoring error return value has to be nil when it is really nil, then it complains that `the return value by the function made by makeFunc is incorrect`

Can you think of a way to solve this problem? (Except wrapping the error in a struct, and changing the return type to that struct instead )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this line to set `secondValue`:

```
secondValue := reflect.ValueOf(&err).Elem()
```

The call `ValueOf(&err)` returns a `reflect.Value` with type `*error`.  Calling `Elem()` on that value returns a `reflect.Value` with type `error`.

The call `ValueOf(err)` returns a `reflect.Value` with the type of the concrete value of `err` or an invalid `reflect.Value` if there is no concrete value in `err` (`err == nil`). Either way, the returned `reflect.Value` does not have type `error`.

Comment: I feel shame about not coming up with this. Thanks a lot